# How can i get which leaves contains which training samples in DecisionTreeClassifier tree in sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn

When using sklearn DecisionTreeClassifier leaves are generated and each leaves contains samples. Currently visualizing this tree shows tree with leaves with number of samples of each class. I want to know exactly which samples fall in which leave?
[A tree representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfNEm.png)

I want to get the samples that fall in each leaves, codes or ideas will be very helpful

Comment: show your code, what you tried, what you get, are there errors.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation of scikit learn explains it, you can use the method `DecisionTreeClassifier.apply(self, X, check_input=True)`, which returns for each of the samples in `X` the ID of the leaf it 'felt' into:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.apply

Otherwise, you could use the method `DecisionTreeClassifier.decision_path(self, X, check_input=True)` to get a 'node indicator matrix where non zero elements indicates that the samples goes through the nodes'.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.decision_path

Thus, the following code may solve your problem:

```
dec_tree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dec_tree.fit(x_train, y_train)

node_id_list = dec_tree.apply(x_train)
```